# How to replace tab with 4 spaces in an existing class in python (spyder)

Tags: python, tabs, spyder, space, spaces

I have to use some existing classes. When I run these I always get the error 'IndentationError: expected an indented block'. I discovered it could be resolved by replacing the tab to 4 spaces.

Because I have a lott of these classes and the classes that I want to use are not small, I was wondering if there is an easy way to replace all tabs with 4 places in one step.
I use Spyder with anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

- Ctrl + R
- Enable Regex (the `.*` symbol right to the first text input).
- Put `\t` in the find text field.
- Put      (4 spaces) in the replace text field.
- Press "All" to replace all text

Answer (score 1):

Open your `.py` file in a text editor, highlight and copy one of the tabs, do a find and replace (usually ctrl + F), paste in the tab that you copied, and replace it with four spaces